# UTF-8 Black Diamond WAMP

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8, wamp

I'm a web developer of 15 years and this problem never fails to cause me issues and there are 1000's of similar questions posted on this topic but I still can't find a definitive answer.

I'm trying to store a '¼' symbol in a MySQL database table. The table stucture is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `denominations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

My page which renders the results:

The pages themselves are saved in the UTF-8 page settings with my editor. Despite this the symbol displays as a black diamond with a question mark.

The server I am running on is a local WAMP installation, my PHP.ini settings has:

default_charset = "UTF-8"

This is an age old problem that is exhausting and boring for us all, but yet again it has beat me. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 1**

The rendered output:

var_dump($denominations);

```
array (size=18)
  1 => string '�' (length=1)
  2 => string '1d' (length=2)
  3 => string '1' (length=1)
```

Comment: Show the actual bytes saved.

Comment: Is the characterset set in the page headers?

Comment: Edit your question to show the code that renders the results.

Comment: There are two cases of black diamonds.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored  Also make sure the browser is set to UTF8